# Create a single heatmap based on two symmetric matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap

Suppose I have two symmetric matrices:

```r
library(Matrix)
set.seed(123)

s1<-forceSymmetric(matrix(round(rnorm(25),2),5))
colnames(s1)<-LETTERS[1:5]
rownames(s1)<-LETTERS[6:10]
diag(s1)<-1

s2<-forceSymmetric(matrix(round(rbinom(25,25,0.3),2),5))
colnames(s2)<-LETTERS[1:5]
rownames(s2)<-LETTERS[6:10]
diag(s2)<-1

s1
# 5 x 5 Matrix of class "dsyMatrix"
# A     B     C     D     E
# F  1.00  1.72  1.22  1.79 -1.07
# G  1.72  1.00  0.36  0.50 -0.22
# H  1.22  0.36  1.00 -1.97 -1.03
# I  1.79  0.50 -1.97  1.00 -0.73
# J -1.07 -0.22 -1.03 -0.73  1.00

s2
# 5 x 5 Matrix of class "dsyMatrix"
# A B  C  D E
# F 1 6  8  7 9
# G 6 1  5  9 8
# H 8 5  1 10 9
# I 7 9 10  1 1
# J 9 8  9  1 1
```

What I wanted is to generate a single heatmap where the upper diagonal and its legend is based on matrix s1 while the lower diagonal and its legend is based on matrix s2. Here is a similar one I can found:

[image]

Comment: Hi @David - I know this is an old post but did you work out how to get to scales for the upper and lower matrix as the example above?

Answer (score 0):

Get upper diagonal

```
reverse = s1[,ncol(s1):1]
diag(reverse) = 0
reverse[lower.tri(reverse, diag = FALSE)] <- 0
upper = reverse[,ncol(reverse):1]
```

Get lower diagonal

```
reverse1 = s2[,ncol(s2):1]
diag(reverse1) = 0
reverse1[upper.tri(reverse1, diag = FALSE)] <- 0
upper1 = reverse1[,ncol(reverse1):1]
```

Time to add them up.

```
merged = as.matrix(upper+upper1)
merged
  A    B     C     D    E
F 1.00 1.72  1.22  1.79 0
G 1.72 1.00  0.36  0.00 8
H 1.22 0.36  0.00 10.00 9
I 1.79 0.00 10.00  1.00 1
J 0.00 8.00  9.00  1.00 1
```

Plot it.

```
heatmap(merged)
```

You can find nicer heatmap plots elsewhere

Comment: Thanks How about the separate legendary?

Comment: Separate legendary? You mean legend? I'd look online for different heatmap tools and see whats available